# Creating a year form in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have created a registration form with a year input (example below) which is returning an array.

```
$this->Form->year('graduation', 1960, date('Y'));
```

The error I am receiving is as follows:

```
    Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 749]
Code | Context
implode - [internal], line ??
DboSource::create() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 749
Model::save() - CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1342
UsersController::register() - APP/controllers/users_controller.php, line 38
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83

Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]
```

I would appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction (an example would be just spot on)

Many thanks in advance!

So I made some changes based on Ross' comment which no longer throws and error:

```
echo $this->Form->input('graduation', array('label' => 'Year of Graduation:',
                                                             'type' => 'date',
                                                             'dateFormat' => 'Y',
                                                             'empty' => true,
                                                             'minYear' => 1960, // start year
                                                             'maxYear' => date('Y') // current 
                                                            )
                                      );
```

Issue now is that even when selecting a year, the value in the database is being stored as null

Answer (score 3):

something like this should do what you're after:

```
echo $this->Form->input('graduation', array('dateFormat' => 'Y',
                                            'minYear' => 1960, // start year
                                            'maxYear' => date('Y') // current 
                                           )
                       );
```

Comment: Your help is much appreciated. I had a similar drop down before, however I only want to have a year only selection.  Is there another way of doing that?

Comment: what's the HTML output of the above? You may need to specify the model too, thinking about it. The name of the field has to be `name="data[Model][graduation][year]"` to work correctly. Try `->input('Model.graduation')` instead, where `Model` is the appropriate one.